# How to Create openerp user through Python code?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

How to Create openerp user through Python code ?

what are the required infor' ? [i tried below but its gives a error ]

```
res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
user_id = super(res_users, res_users_obj).create(cr, uid, {'login':'given_name' ,'password':'given_name'}, context=context)
```

my requirement is that ,
I need to create user when i'm create a employee

please help me to sort out this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override the create method of `hr.employee` like.

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    user_vals = {
        'name': vals.get('name'),
        'login': default_login,
        #and other required field 
    }
    user_obj.create(cr, uid, user_vals, context)
    return super(hr_employee, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

Comment: thanks dear Atul :-)
wat are the required fields.? for ex what have to enter to partner_id.?

Comment: @atul, What is that default_login?